# printf() formatting for hex uint32_t without missing zeros. (in c89)

Tags: c, format, hex, printf

Wanted to print uint32 hex.
Tried "PRIx32", looked bad to me:

```
967407c0 23 4481d55f ffffff52 de3cd140
2fc aa7363cf fffff40d 563270c0 2b86
```

So... tried this. Dirty but worked:

```
 /*******************************************************************************
 Print a digit in hex.
 *******************************************************************************/
 void mpal_digit_t_print_hex(
     mpal_digit_t * input)
 {
     uint8_t p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_7, p_8;

     p_1 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 0) >> 28);
     p_2 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 4) >> 28);
     p_3 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 8) >> 28);
     p_4 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 12) >> 28);
     p_5 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 16) >> 28);
     p_6 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 20) >> 28);
     p_7 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 24) >> 28);
     p_8 = (uint8_t)(((*input) << 28) >> 28);

     printf(" %" PRIx8 "%" PRIx8 "%" PRIx8 "%" PRIx8 "%" PRIx8 "%" PRIx8 "%"
            PRIx8 "%" PRIx8 "", p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_7, p_8);
     return;
 }
```

Output:

```
 61dd90ef ff6df47e a0a9abc0 011d7394 2311761f
 f4402427 5c44ca40 0f86aba7 6aa5194f ecb9ed1e
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those "symbolic" printf specifiers like `PRIx32` are designed to be used with extra flags, if you need them.  So you can do something like this:

```
printf("%08" PRIx32, hexval);
```

After string concatenation, this will typically turn into either `%08x` or `%08lx`.  `8` specifies you want (at least) 8 digits, and `0` specifies 0-padding.

Comment: Alternately, one can use "% .8x" PRIx32

Comment: @chqrlie I suppose, but you've got an extra `x`.

Comment: Yes of course! commenting with the android app is a pain. The alternate format string is `printf("%.8" PRIx32, hexval);`. This format is useful when you need both `0` filling and a larger minimum width.